# Error while deployig build through TFS express 2012

Tags: deployment, tfs, build

I am getting the following error while I am trying to deploy build using TFS express 2012 team build:

C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (1737): Value cannot be null.Parameter name: type

C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (1737): Filename: redirection.config
Error: Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions